# How to manually customize parameters of DRF views using drf-yasg Swagger?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I am using `drf-yasg` package to integrate Swagger with DRF.

As documentation said I used `@swagger_auto_schema` decorator to manually customize auto-generated endpoints. After a lot of tries I still can't figure out why there are no any changes.

So, I tried to add extra query parameter to `RetrieveUpdateAPIView`:

```
class MyCustomView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    ...

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        manual_parameters=[openapi.Parameter('test', openapi.IN_QUERY, description="test manual param", type=openapi.TYPE_BOOLEAN)]
    )
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

After all, nothing seems changed. What exactly I have to do then?

Comment: Did you go to localhost:8000/swagger and see new test param in custom view endpoint as I copy-paste the code and see changes. Did you import openapi and swagger_auto_schema?

Comment: I'm using `django_filters` with which is drf swagger compatible. You may have a look at it :]

Answer (score 3):

A `query_serializer` parameter was added in 1.18 (https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/pull/17).

Example:

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from rest_framework import viewsets
    from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
    
    class CustomParametersSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        myparam = serializers.CharField(help_text="My manual querystring parameter")

    class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
        @swagger_auto_schema(query_serializer=CustomParametersSerializer)
        def my_route(self, request):
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `swagger_auto_schema` in get method instead of retrieve.

```
@swagger_auto_schema(
        manual_parameters=[openapi.Parameter('test', openapi.IN_QUERY, description="test manual param", type=openapi.TYPE_BOOLEAN)]
    )
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Comment: This is not an answer. The OP asked how to specify a schema for class-based view and your answer is for function-based view.